# Three20 framework in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to know how to use the three20 frame work in my project,i want to create a image gallery for my app.Please give a correct method of  adding  three20 to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually looked at [three20's official website documentation](http://three20.info/documentation) on how to add three20 to your code?

As for how to use it, after downloading the package take a look at the sample folder they have. It should give you a general idea on how to use it.

Comment: Since Xcode 4.2 is the latest, there isn't an Xcode 4.3. Are you talking about your iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

## Use the following code on terminal to add three20

> python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/your/project/project.xcodeproj Three20
>   Steps:

```
1) Open Terminal
2) type "python"
3) Locate "ttmodule.py" file & drag it on Terminal
4) -p
5) locate your project xcode file & drag to terminal
6) Three20
7)Press enter Three20 will be added to your project
```

Another way:

```
1)Open your project
2)Open three20 xcode project
3) drag three20 project in your project
```